# What is the fastest way to get a UK passport?

Tags: uk, passports

I'm in need of a replacement UK adult passport, as fast as possible.

What would be the fastest process be to get one? Online or physically going somewhere? (I'm unsure of the process as of yet, so the premise of that question could be wrong)

**Note**:

- Money isn't a factor, nor' is traveling somewhere in the UK.
- My old passport is lost. (That too was an adult passport)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the UK, HM Passport Office offer two options for urgent passport renewal: Premium and Fast Track.

Premium renewal is a same day service, but only for renewal and name changes of adult passports, where the existing passport is available and undamaged.

Fast Track renewal is a one week service, covering all renewals and changes, as well as new child passports (but not new adult passports).

Since your previous passport was lost, you cannot use Premium renewal. The fee for renewing a lost adult passport using Fast Track [is currently £103](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently/cost).

---

To begin a Premium or Fast Track renewal, you'll need to [book an appointment](https://www.passportappointment.service.gov.uk/outreach/publicbooking.ofml) at a Passport Customer Service Centre. You'll need to take a filled-in paper application form (which you can get from a Post Office) to your appointment, as well as any required supporting documents including passport photos.

Comment: Looks like it's a day trip to London on Saturday then, Thanks alot for the answer @waiwai933