# UK Passport: Emergency appointment (supporting documents)

Tags: uk, passports

I asked [What is the fastest way to get a UK passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92410/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-a-uk-passport) yesterday. (27/04/17) and the results of that was:

I have booked an appointment for a 1 week emergency passport. I'm currently filling out the application form to take to the interview with me (29/04/17) and I really don't want to get this wrong (as I'll be traveling [to London](http://www.passports-office.co.uk/passport_office_london.asp) from Nottingham).

---

### Documentation (thus far)

- I have two identical photos which abide by the guidelines set out by ['Her Majesty's Passport Office'](http://www.passports-office.co.uk/passport_photos.asp) with a countersigned signatory (from a professional person who has known me for at-least two years).
- I have also collected a paper application form from my local post office.
- I have the appointment reference number which will help me gain access to the Passport Office.

---

### The Confusion

- The gentleman at the post office said I won't require any supporting documents as I have had a passport previously and my details haven't changed.
- The guidelines set out in [*Guidance For Attending Urgent Appointments*](http://www.passports-office.co.uk/blog/urgent_passport_appointments/) says the opposite:

> • All supporting documents - Current Passport, Birth/Marriage/Civil Partnership Certificates or Deed Poll Confirmation etc.

---

### Question

Will I be required to take any supporting documents with me to the interview, if so, what will I be required to take?

The [booklet](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/604696/Guidance_Booklet_March_2017__ILB_44_03.17__Tagged.pdf) doesn't really specify much on supporting documents except the aforementioned block quote.

---

**Notes**:

- I have had both a child passport and an adult passport previously.
- I have the child passport details i.e. passport number etc.. (which is clipped/expired) but not the physical passport (in a different city in the UK).
- The previous UK adult passport was lost.

**Update:**

I didn't need the appointment reference number to access the building, just my surname and date of birth. Also, I advise you to go into the building atleast 15 minutes before your appointment as you queue up to go through a security checkpoint at the entrance.

Comment: I would put more credence in pretty much anyone's advice than someone at the post office. The internet abounds with anecdata about the uselessness of the 'check & send' service...

Comment: @AakashM In this instance, the gentleman at the post office was correct. So, your assumption is factually wrong.

Comment: Just because the gentleman at the post office was correct, doesn't mean the probability of achieving that result was ever particularly high... or that it will be next time.

Comment: So, what's the probability of someone on the internet being more right? it'll be exactly the same because it's hypothetical. My point was to assume something that actually worked out, isn't a valid assumption at all. If he stated that he had done the same thing and the gentleman at the post office was incorrect, then it would be a fair statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### For this particular situation, you are not required to take any supporting documents with you, but to answer Section 3C of the paper form to the best of your knowledge.

---

As the query is from within the UK it is best to call [*Her Majesties Passport Office Advice and Complaints Line*](https://www.gov.uk/passport-advice-line) on **0300 222 0000** and follow the options with the automated line (in regards to advice about an application process, not applying itself) until you reach an operator.

They will advise you (for this particular situation) to:

- Fill in **Section 3** of the paper application form.
- They will also tell you that you **won't** need any supporting documents as you've had a passport before and your details haven't changed (i.e. your name on the deed poll is the same etc...)
- But, they will ask you to answer **Section 3C** specifically to **the best of your knowledge** and the criteria for that is:

> ### Section 3
>
> **C**: Details of the lost and stolen passport
>
> 1. Issued at (Month and Year)
> 2. Holders surname at the time it was issued
> 3. First and Middle names
> 4. How the passport was lost, or why it is not available
> 5. Date of loss
> 6. Place of loss

This information would suffice for the application and the interview process (including the aforementioned documentation already accumulated)

Comment: In my experience the telephone line is a waste of time and is designed to stall you [to reduce load on the physical offices] rather than help you.

Comment: @Calchas but, it did help me?

Comment: I didn't see that you are answering your own question. Since this actually was helpful for you, please ignore my comment. It comes from a few grumpy experiences with people on that telephone line.

Comment: @Calchas don't worry. I'm as cynical as you about these things, but they were actually surprisingly helpful _this time_.

Comment: Photo attestations are not required if you are renewing and if the photos bear a reasonable likeness to your last passport (which is generally the case for adults).

Comment: Renewing a lost passport or generally? The latter would be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I have already up voted, my comment is for info only because it always helps to be specific about scope.